# How do I load a new contentView with the OnTouchEvent multiple times

Tags: java, android

How do I load a new contentView with OnTouchEvent more than once? I have 4 splash screens I want to display them after the user touches the previous splash. I'm trying to use booleans and if statements to load them but it won't let me change the value of the boolean within the if.

Thank you very much!

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // return super.onTouchEvent(e);

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && intro1() == false) {
        intro1();

    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && intro2() == false) {
        intro2();
    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && intro3() == false) {
        intro3();
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean intro1() {

    setContentView(R.layout.splash2);
    return false;
}

public boolean intro2() {

    setContentView(R.layout.splash3);
    return false;
}

public boolean intro3() {

    setContentView(R.layout.splash4);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
int splash=0;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// return super.onTouchEvent(e);

if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  {
    switch (splash++) {
     case 1:
      intro1();
      break;
     case 2:
      intro2();
      break;
     case 3:
      intro3();
      break;
      default:
      //do someting else
    }
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: Your welcome.  If you liked it click on the up arrow at the top left of the answer.